# How can I install Dev C++ in Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, command-line, software-installation, c++, compiler

I want to use [Dev C++](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B) in Ubuntu. Is it available in Ubuntu? If yes, please tell me how I can install it with terminal (by command-line)?

Comment: What is " Dev C++"?

Answer (score 3):

Dev-c++ is basically a Windows program, with some work done to port to Unix like environments (cygnwin, Linux, etc).  Run it under wine if you like, it's rated by winehq as silver or platinum, depending upon which version you select.